# Lightroom -> How to change pre-select fields in Import window?

Tags: lightroom, import

Since a long time now, everytime I open the "Import" window, the fields are pre-selected with some datas. I never find a way to change that.

On the picture below, the red part are always pre-selected with a specific value (and one I don't use often of course), so I need to change thoses values everytime.

Any way how to change that ? All articles I can find talk about having preset, but I'm looking to "reset" default values.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that the "Source folder" is also always the same. It's really annoying, because that folder doesn't exist anymore, so everytime I open the "Import" box, I've got an alert "This folder doesn't exist anymore".

Answer (score 1):

Those options should retain their value after you change it and import something. If that's not what happens, it might be that something has gone wrong with your Lightroom installation. The best way to fix this might be to take a backup of your catalog and perform a reinstall of the program.

It should be fairly easy to do if you're an Adobe CC subscriber. You can go to the Adobe CC client and uninstall the program from there. It should ask to retain your settings. In this case it might be a good idea to delete those, but make sure to take a backup of your catalog files to an external location to make sure it doesn't get deleted in the process.

Comment: I've clean up all cache and settings file, and it works, it reset the values. 
I didn't check it so much after that, but I'm not sure the problem is fix.